# Prepared statement Parameter index out of range (0 < 1 )

Tags: java, jdbc, prepared-statement

Am not expert on web application, recently am writing a small webapp for my mobile app using servlets. My agenda is to receive data from client, and to put it into db. everything is running fine except, my database insert statement,which am trying to achieve using PreparedStatement.

```
// This is how my insert statement looks like
private String INSERT_INTO_DEVICES = "INSERT INTO travlemate.devices (owner,"
        + "deviceid,gcmid) VALUES (?,?,?)"; 

// This is how am trying to insert
PreparedStatement preparedStmt = mConn.prepareStatement(INSERT_INTO_DEVICES);
preparedStmt.setString(0, data.getDeviceNumber());
preparedStmt.setString(1, data.getDeviceID());
preparedStmt.setString(2,data.getGcmId());
preparedStmt.execute();
mConn.close();
```

but while executing this task, am receiving following exception

```
java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (0 < 1 ).
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:910)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.setInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2791)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.setString(PreparedStatement.java:3627)
    at com.mkgcorp.travelweb.data.DataManager.registerGCMData(DataManager.java:35)
    at com.mkgcorp.travelweb.controller.Loader.doPost(Loader.java:46)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:644)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:537)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1085)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:658)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:222)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1556)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1513)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I seriously tried all sorts of thing which am capable of, but this exception is not going away, any idea on same?

Thanks,
Techfist

Comment: It's one of those annoying little differences, but prepared statement indices start at 1 not 0

Answer (score 39, accepted):

`PreparedStatement` parameter indices start at `1`

```
preparedStmt.setString(1, data.getDeviceNumber());
...
```

Comment: so stupid of me, why cant throughout they follow same zero based indexing its really to hard to remember where which indexing to follow.

Comment: whoever designed it probably thought using natural language indexing was a good idea, i.e `1st`, `2nd` ;)

Answer (score 6):

```
PreparedStatement preparedStmt = mConn.prepareStatement(INSERT_INTO_DEVICES);
preparedStmt.setString(1, data.getDeviceNumber());
preparedStmt.setString(2, data.getDeviceID());
preparedStmt.setString(3,data.getGcmId());
preparedStmt.execute();
mConn.close();
```

Jdbc parameters are not zero-indexed. It starts with 1 , as all the indexes in database related statements start with 1.