# java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (4 > number of parameters, which is 3)

Tags: java, mysql, sql

```
private void changeButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             
        try {
            Connection con = getConnection();
            PreparedStatement pa = con.prepareStatement("Uptade mstock Set (mehsul_adi,  mehsul_ceki , mehsul_tarix ) values(?,?,?) WHERE mehsul_kodu='?' ");
             pa.setString(1, mehsul_adi.getText());
                pa.setString(2,mehsul_ceki.getText());
                 SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
              
               String tarix = dateFormat.format(mehsul_tarix.getDate());
                pa.setString(3, tarix);
               pa.setInt(PROPERTIES, Integer.valueOf(mehsul_kodu.getText()));
               pa.executeUpdate();
               JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Yeniliklər yadda saxlanıldı.");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why is this question tagged c#? Don't use extra tags to attract more attention to your question. That type of thing doesn't go over well here.

Comment: Note that you are using hardcoded values 1, 2 and 3 to point at indices, while your data structure (which you neglected to include) is likely zero-based, meaning the indices should be 0, 1 and 2.

Comment: Instead of 1,2 and 3 try using 0,1 and 2

Comment: @MarsAtomic, @ChetanRanpanya, parameter indices for `PreparedStatement` [start from 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27592500/prepared-statement-parameter-index-out-of-range-0-1)

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues in the code snippet to be addressed:

- Invalid SQL syntax of `UPDATE` query
- Possibly incorrect index of the 4th query parameter (`pa.setInt(PROPERTIES,...)`)
- It's recommended to use `try-with-resources` for auto-closable `Connection` object.
- Move the DB update out of the `actionPerformed` implementation into a separate method `updateMstock()`

That being said, the following code should resolve all the mentioned issues:

```java
private void changeButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             
    updateMstock();
}

private void updateMstock() {
    try (Connection con = getConnection()) {
        PreparedStatement pa = con.prepareStatement(
            "UPDATE mstock SET mehsul_adi=?,  mehsul_ceki=?, mehsul_tarix=? WHERE mehsul_kodu=? "
        );

        pa.setString(1, mehsul_adi.getText());
        pa.setString(2, mehsul_ceki.getText());

        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
              
        String tarix = dateFormat.format(mehsul_tarix.getDate());
        pa.setString(3, tarix);
        pa.setInt(4, Integer.valueOf(mehsul_kodu.getText()));
        pa.executeUpdate();

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Yeniliklər yadda saxlanıldı.");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: If you think the answer is fine, it's better to upvote it/mark it as accepted (place a green tick) than just to post a "thank you" comment :)